# warning message doesn't work for user-form

Tags: vba, excel

My content in sheet2 was hidden and only after user form popped up and enter the password before the content can unhide. However with the warning message, even after I select "yes to terminate" my sheet content still unhides.

**Expected outcome:**
After the user selects "yes to terminate" on the warning message, it is suppose to drop the user form. Can anyone help me solve it?

**Under worksheet(sheet2):**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If Sheets("Reference").Columns("A:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
        Password.Show
        Call unhide
    Else
        Sheets("Reference").Columns("A:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

**Under userform (Password):**

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    If Me.Pword.Value = "123" Then
        Unload Me
        Call unhide
    Else
        Me.Hide
        Retry = MsgBox("The password is incorrect. Do you wish to try again?", _
            vbYesNo, "Retry?")
        Select Case Retry
            Case Is = vbYes
                Me.Pword.Value = ""
                Me.Pword.SetFocus
                Me.Show
            Case Is = vbNo
                Unload Me
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
    If ExitAsk = vbYes Then Unload Password
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        If Not ExitAsk = vbYes Then Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ExitAsk() As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim Smsg As String
    Smsg = "Do you really want to exit? Click Yes to Quit or No to Continue."
    ExitAsk = MsgBox(Smsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2 + vbQuestion, "Exit!")
End Function
```

Comment: Is `If Not ExitAsk = vbYes Then Cancel = True` the line that is supposed to exit?

Comment: Perhaps you could re-phrase your question to make it more clear what you're trying to do, and where the problem lies.

Comment: `even after I select "yes to terminate" my sheet content still unhides.` isn't this to do with the fact that you call `Call unhide` under your worksheet?

Comment: yes to terminate means "yes" to exit userform